Gradle access in Docker container for Cordova app behind restrictive firewall
My task is to set up a Docker container to build the Android version of a Cordova app.
The build server which runs the Docker container is behind a restrictive company firewall. Packages have to be downloaded from the companies' Artifactory.
In the Dockerfile, I download and install the gradle-8.7-bin.zip via Artifactory in the folder /opt/gradle and added /opt/gradle/bin to the PATH.
However, during runtime, when the build server executes
cordova build android gradle is downloaded again even though the version (gradle -v) is correctly identified as 8.7.
Because of the firewall settings, the default download from services.gradle.org fails.
As a workaround, I successfully set the environment variable
CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL to the gradle package path in Artifactory. (Kudos to Unable to build an android gradle project - for a cordova project and Install gradle for using in cordova build android) However this delays the build process and I would prefer cordova to use the gradle version that is installed already.
This related question why is cordova downloading gradle again? suggests to check the environment variables which all seem fine.
Also related: Automatic gradle download instead of local gradle in cordova. However, the suggested advice of the sole answer "then rebuild it" is unsatisfactory.
